# Azure Pipelines multirepository CI trigger works only for .yml files in default branch

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have 2 repositories. One contains code and another one contains pipeline definitions. But when I create pipelines with CI trigger for code repository, only pipelines from default branch are executed. I need the way to configure branch from which pipeline should be executed, but unfortunately setting `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds` don't work for me.

My test case:

I have code repository (named portal_repo) with `stackoverflow` branch that triggers pipeline.

I have 2 branches in the pipeline repository [(images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzJ8y.png):

- `stackoverflow-default` is a default branch for pipeline repository.
- `stackoverflow-pipeline-branch` is a branch I want pipeline to be executed.

I have .yml file with pipeline definition in each of this branches:
[(.yml files image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPXZk.png)

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: portal_repo
    type: git
    name: SmartDecisionHub/sb-df.react
    ref: stackoverflow
    trigger:
     branches:
       include:
       - stackoverflow

trigger: none

        
stages:
- stage: Echo
  jobs:
  - job: Echo
    steps:
    - checkout: none

    - bash: |
        echo "Hello trigger from default branch!" # in `stackoverflow-default` branch
        echo "Hello trigger from pipeline branch!" # in `stackoverflow-pipeline-branch` branch
```

I set `stackoverflow-pipeline-branch` as a `Default branch for manual and scheduled builds` [(Settings img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTxbw.png)

But still CI trigger always executes for .yml file in `stackoverflow-default` branch:

[Executed from default branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCqux.png)

[Output from default branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oksia.png)

I expect pipeline to run from `stackoverflow-pipeline-branch` not from `stackoverflow-default`.

Comment: Hi dron_days, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can I make a suggestion? Instead of linking to screenshots, your question would be much improved if you wrote out the information in text in the question itself, copying and pasting as needed. Remember, you are encouraged to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76760211/edit) your question to improve it.

Comment: Hi Vince Bowdren, thank you for your suggestion, this really useful and I think that this is how it should be, but unfortunately, I can't. When I tried to do so, I was notified that I don't have enough reputation to post images directly.

Comment: In resources definition you are referrencing 'stackoverflow' branch as trigger for 'portal_repo'. Try using wildcard at the end of the branch. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#wildcards
From my experience YAML definition has always precedence before GUI definition.

Comment: @dron_days I mean to not use images at all, and describe everything in text.

Comment: Vince Bowdren thank you for your suggestion, I extended text description.

Comment: @Danielson thank you for your suggestion, but portal_repo CI trigger works fine. The problem is when I push changes to portal_repo `stackoverflow` branch, the pipeline executes from default branch in pipeline repository (`stackoverflow-default`) not from the branch I configured it should be executed (`stackoverflow-pipeline-branch`)